# Comparing Doctrine Entities; Bring all data back or make each call to the database

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to figure out the best solution both in performance and in terms of the least error prone. I lack enough experience to know which of my solutions is the best.

I have a Person table like so:

```
ID        FB_ID          Name
1         68486          John Smith
2         88858          Jayne Smith
3         56669          Brian Smith
4                        Joe No_id
5                        Dupes Possible
6                        Dupes Possible
```

I'm connecting using the FB SDK to bring back a list of the members in a group I admin. This list from Facebook I consider to be the master list and my table needs to be updated periodically.

For the update I have two scenarios, but I'm unsure which one is the best solution in terms of performance and ease of implementation. Each scenario will require iteration over the list from Facebook.

**Scenario 1:**
Bring back all the users from my table and during the Facebook iteration find matches by iterating over the users from my table:

```
$peopleList = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Person')->findAll();

foreach($fbpeople as $p){
    //Find person entity with a matching FB ID
      //If found perform updates, etc.
    //Not found, now search again for the name
      //Found, add FB ID
    //Not found do an insert
}
```

With this first scenario I have a single call to the database for the initial data fetch and then some additional calls after for any data updates or inserts, but what is problematic is iterating over the user list and ensuring that the data is current and modifying elements in an array while traversing it.

**Scenario 2:** While iterating over the list from Facebook I search for the users in the database.

```
foreach($fbpeople as $p){
    $person = $personRepository->findOneBy(array('FB_ID' => $p['ID']));

    //Found? perform update

    //Not found? search again by name
    $person = $personRepository->findOneBy(array('name' => $p['name']));

    //etc
}
```

With this scenario there are many more calls to the database. On that note there are only about 1100 members and explosive growth is not likely. In fact I estimate that the upper bounds of membership would be well below 5000 members.

Of the two scenarios which would present a better solution in terms of performance and reduced possibility of errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the possibility of duplicate names I've indeed had to loop over the list every time.

Answer (score 1):

If your solution #1 is ok memory-wise for you I'd use it with slight modification:

```
$ppl = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Person')->findAll();
$peopleList = [];
foreach ($ppl as $person) {
    // one is always available according to your desc
    $peopleList[$person->getFbId() ?: $person->getName()] = $person;
}
foreach($fbpeople as $p){
    if (isset($peopleList[$p->id])) {
        // found by id, modify
    } elseif (isset($peopleList[$p->name])) {
        // Found, add FB ID
    } else {
        // Not found, create new Person and persist it
    }
}
```

Thanks to using associative array you'll prevent iterating 2 times over an array in case of a miss with both ID and name (which will be way more performant). You might want to fine tune how you save entities though as Doctrine might be a bit slow when speaking about thousands of objects in it.

Comment: The part where we copy the list of people and add new keys is excellent thinking, however the issue I have seen with this is that with 1000+ people in the local database and on the first run no one has a FbID there are a couple of people with the same 'name' value (e.g. 2 John Smith). I'm going to use what you have though and build on it to come up with a solution.